# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns 0?

Tags: c#, json

I am attempting to write a Windows form app that pulls player data via a text file formatted in json but have run into issues. Any data I try to deserialize returns a 0 value in my text box.... I am new to coding and stuck, any help would be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("textfile");

StatsCounts newStats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatsCounts>(json);

earningsTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(newStats.earnings);
```

My Json Class Formating:

```
public class StatsCounts
{
    public int earnings { get; set; }
    public int firsts { get; set; }
    public int seconds { get; set; }
    public int thirds { get; set; }
    public int starts { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public StatsCounts statsCounts { get; set; }
}
```

And my text file formatting:

```
{
    "statsCounts": {
    "earnings": 4576702,
    "firsts": 131,
    "seconds": 102,
    "thirds": 80,
    "starts": 590
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? What do you have in newStats after deserialization?

Comment: Surely you should be deserializing using `RootObject`?

Comment: That was it! I need to use RootObject. Thank you canton7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialize for the type `RootObject`, not `StatsCounts`, so it should read:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{\n    \"statsCounts\": {\n    \"earnings\": 4576702,\n    \"firsts\": 131,\n    \"seconds\": 102,\n    \"thirds\": 80,\n    \"starts\": 590\n    }\n}");
    var a = Convert.ToString(rootObject.statsCounts.earnings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct classes, but you're not using them.  Use `RootObject` to deserialize into.

Change to this:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
StatsCounts newStats = results.statsCounts;
```